# Why Doesn't Yum Clean Up Orphaned Packages?

Tags: fedora, yum

I recently used Yum (on Fedora 13) to install `xmms2`. It found some dependencies and installed those as well. Immediately after I installed `xmms2`, I performed `yum erase xmms2`, but it uninstalled only the `xmms2` package, and not the packages that were installed along with it to resolve dependencies. I also tried performing `package-cleanup --orphans`, but it doesn't list those packages. What is happening here? Shouldn't the other packages be uninstalled as well?

Comment: Though this is an old question, it's also worth pointing out that part of the issue here is that yum terminology is a bit different. That's why 'package-cleanup --orphans' didn't work as expected — because an "orphan" isn't what you think.    

Packages that don't exist as dependencies (aren't required by any other installed package) are called **leaves** in yum. An "orphaned" package is one that's installed on the system, but not available in any configured repository. So, any rpm installed by hand, from a disabled repo, or that's been removed from its source repo since it was installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a design decision that was made long, long ago. install `yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves` if they irk you so.

Answer (score 4):

If someone ends up here in this old question....

just use

```
yum autoremove
```

It will work like running clean_requirements_on_remove turned on.
It will remove your stubborn packages. ;-)

(I use CentOS 7)

Answer (score 3):

In yum-3.2.28-13 it does remove orphaned packages with `clean_requirements_on_remove=1` under `[main]` in `/etc/yum.conf`. According to this link: [Testing yum’s autoremove orphaned deps feature](http://blog.christophersmart.com/2010/11/11/testing-yums-autoremove-orphaned-deps-feature/).

Comment: Works like a charm. Why isn't this behaviour default?